# How to left join and divide value by columns matched in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tables one contains utms and the other is cost.
I would like to join on the medium and network and location and divide the joined value using medium and network amongst the matched items locations. For example

| network | medium | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| facebook | CPC | tokyo |
| facebook | CPC | Singapore |
| facebook | CPC | tokyo |
| facebook | CPC | Malaysia |
| google ads | CPC | singapore |
| google ads | CPC | maldives |

| network | medium | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| facebook | cpc | 4 |
| google ads | cpc | 4 |

into

| network | medium | location | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| facebook | CPC | tokyo | 1 |
| facebook | CPC | Singapore | 1 |
| facebook | CPC | tokyo | 1 |
| facebook | CPC | Malaysia | 1 |
| google ads | CPC | singapore | 2 |
| google ads | CPC | maldives | 2 |

so the cost divides itsef amongst the location that matches network and medium

Answer (score 0):

consider below approach

```
select u.*, cost / count(*) over(partition by u.network, u.medium) as cost
from utms u
left join costs c
on lower(u.network) = lower(c.network)
and lower(u.medium) = lower(c.medium)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried? does it work for you?